# Why do we always use arrays for bytes

Tags: .net, arrays

In built-in .NET libraries there are tons of classes and methods that accept input or return values in the form of bytes:

```
byte[] result = MemoryStream.ToArray()
byte[] result = Convert.FromBase64String("...")
byte[] result = File.ReadAllBytes("filename")
byte[] result = HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync().Result
Guid guid = new Guid(new byte[] { ... })
```

And all those methods return or accept bytes in the form of an array. (Maybe this is also the case with other languages and platforms - it's just I work mainly with .NET).

I'm curious to know why we always use arrays for bytes and never use other data structures (lists, collections, ...). I know that most of these methods were introduced before generic classes appeared in .NET, but `HttpClient`, for example, was introduced much later, and it still uses arrays.

Comment: Because there is no need for methods such as Add, Remove... these arrays are usually meant to be used as is. For example you load that array and send it somewhere else. Byte array is the smallest type of collection you can have, so it takest the least amount of space. Also you can convert it to whatever you want. With `Lists` or other types there might be a problem.

Comment: `IReadOnlyCollection` and `IEnumerable` also have no methods such as Add, Remove. Why no use those? As for taking up the least amount of space - this is definitely an advantage, but arrays also have [disadvantages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/). Does taking up little space outweigh those?

Comment: @AndreBorges IReadOnlyCollection and IEnumerable are interfaces - you still need a concrete type that implements that. And [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) implements IEnumerable and ICollection (and others)

Comment: @HansKesting, Array also supports changing its values, which should not logically be possible for in examples I provided. It makes no sense to modify the byte array that I just got as a result of a web request. The result of a web request is logically immutable, so a decent type to return from `HttpClient` would be `IReadOnlyCollection<byte>`

Comment: You may or may not want to change byte array. It depends on what you're doing. There is no reason to limit these functions. There might be a case where you want to remove last two bytes from your request. If that's the case you would need to copy whole list to array and remove last two bytes.